# How to upload multiple input with same name with appendchild

Tags: php, laravel, database, forms, request

I want to upload data to database which is in 1 div I got many inputs here's my code

```
<div class="fill mb-5" id="clone_input">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="image_content mb-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
            <img src="#" id="fill_preview" alt="" width="100%" class="rounded-1">
            <div class="dots" id="dots_option" onclick="dots_option()"><I class="bi bi-three-dots-vertical rounded-circle"></I></div>
            <div class="image_option" id="image_option">
                <span class="text-danger" onclick="delete_image()"><I class="bi bi-trash"></I> Hapus Gambar</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title[]" placeholder="Masukkan Judul" class="form-control title-fill">
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description[]" placeholder="Deskripsi (boleh kosong)" class="form-control desc-fill">
    </div>
    <div class="input-select mt-2">
        <div class="start">
            <select name="input_type[]" id="input_type" class="form-select">
                @foreach ($inputType as $input)
                    <option value="{{ $input->id }}">{{ $input->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <div class="clone_option" id="clone_option">
                <div class="subject mt-3 px-2" id="subject" style="display: none">
                    <label for="option" class="form-label">Opsi 1 :</label>
                    <textarea name="option" id="option" cols="10" rows="1" class="form-control bg-info bg-opacity-10 border border-info rounded-end"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="cloned_option" id="cloned_option"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="plus_option mt-3 px2" role="button" id="plus_option" style="display: none" onclick="cloneOption()">
                <span class="text-primary">Tambah opsi</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="end">
            <label for="image_fill" id="image_label" class="form-label"><I class="bi bi-image"></I></label>
            <input type="file" id="image_fill" name="image_fill[]" hidden>

            <a class="text-danger" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="remove(this)"><I class="bi bi-trash"></I></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thats was div for cloning, so if I clone it will add new div with same name n id,here's in my controller

```
$countContent = count($request->id);

for ($I=0; $I < $countContent; $I++) {
    if ($request->hasFile('image_fill')) {
        $files = $request->file('image_fill');
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $update = Form_content::create([
                'title' => $request->title[$key],
                'description' => $request->description[$key],
                'image_fill' => $request->image_fill[$key]->hashName(),
                'input_id' => $request->input_type[$key],
                'form_id' => $forms->id
            ]);
        }
        foreach ($request->title as $key => $value) {
            $update = Form_content::where('image_fill', $request->file('image_fill'))->update([
                'title' => $request->title[$key],
                'description' => $request->description[$key],
                'input_id' => $request->input_type[$key],
                'form_id' => $forms->id
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($request->title as $key => $value) {
            $update = Form_content::create([
                'title' => $request->title[$key],
                'description' => $request->description[$key],
                'input_id' => $request->input_type[$key],
                'form_id' => $forms->id
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to upload it in 1 click but when I upload it, if I got 3 input file, when I submit, in db the data are same all of it

Comment: fyi, "_multiple input with same name and id_" Multiple inputs/elements with the same `id` is invalid - `id`s must be unique

Comment: oh sorry i mean with same name*

Answer (score 0):

You can define your key array for order the inputs.

You can make the inputs an array adding `[]` at the end of the name (like your code), don't repeat the ID should be unique.

```
<form>
    <textarea name="text-area[1]">textarea 1</textarea>
    <textarea name="text-area[2]">textarea 2</textarea>
    <textarea name="text-area[3]">textarea 3</textarea>
    <textarea name="text-area[4]">textarea 4</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="image[1]" value="an image url"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="image[2]" value="an image url"/>
    <textarea name="text-area[5]">textarea 5</textarea>
    <input type="text" name="text-input[1]" value="text 1"/>
    <input type="text" name="text-input[2]" value=""text 2"/>
</form>
```

This will put all the values in an array and in your controller you can iterate over

```
foreach (Request::get('text-area') as $textAreaInput) {
    //Logic here
}

foreach (Request::get('image') as $imgageInput) {
    //Logic here
}

foreach (Request::get('text-input') as $textInput) {
    //Logic here
}
```

Comment: how if im using appendchild method? i cant input the [] value

Comment: You don't need the key, just use `input-name[]`. When appendchild, repeat all the code block. If was inside the same form will be send together

Comment: Be careful with that approach though - because it will stop working properly, if your form "rows" that get repeated, were to contain checkboxes. Those will only cause an entry in the form submission data set, _if_ they were checked. So you can't use `name="foo[]"` in such a case, because the index in that array will start to diverge from those in your other arrays, that result from text input fields. In such a case you really don't have much of a different choice, then to explicitly specify the index in the field names upfront.